# Change y-axis limits in pgfpltots

Tags: pgfplots

I am not sure why my graph is not taking the data from the \filecontents data.csv file, but I wanted to change the scale of the y-axis to go from 0 to .005.

Thanks for your help.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable, booktabs}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots, matrix}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10, title/.append style={align =center}}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
  Iter  abs11  abs21  abs12  abs22
     1, 0.0016930, 0.0007109, 0.0169301, 0.0071087
     2, 0.0004656, 0.0006430, 0.0046563, 0.0064301
     3, 0.0001496, 0.0010624, 0.0014964, 0.0106239
     4, 0.0000946, 0.0006596, 0.0009458, 0.0065962
     5, 0.0000274, 0.0002370, 0.0002737, 0.0023697
     6, 0.0000388, 0.0001168, 0.0003882, 0.0011681
     7, 0.0000232, 0.0001592, 0.0002324, 0.0015921
     8, 0.0000073, 0.0001997, 0.0000728, 0.0019965
     9, 0.0001358, 0.0002963, 0.0013578, 0.0029635
    10, 0.0000410, 0.0002793, 0.0004099, 0.0027925
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotsset{minor grid style={dashed,red}}
\pgfplotsset{major grid style={dotted,green!50!black}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={
  group size= 1  by 2,
  vertical sep=2cm,
  horizontal sep = 2cm,
  ylabels at=edge left,group name=ape},
  width=15cm,
  height=8cm,
  try min ticks=5,
  ]
\nextgroupplot[align =center, 
title={\textbf{\emph{(a) RSLE Absolute Errors with $\mathbf{N(0,0.001^{2})}$}}}, 
grid=both, every major grid/.style={gray, opacity=0.5}
]

\addplot [only marks,mark=*,red,mark options={scale=.65}]table[x index=0,y index=1,col sep=comma, green, only marks] {data.csv};\label{plots:plot1}
\addplot [only marks,mark=*,blue,mark options={scale=.65}]table[x index=0,y index=2,col sep=comma, green, only marks] {data.csv};\label{plots:plot2}
\coordinate (top) at (rel axis cs:0,1);

\nextgroupplot[title = {\textbf{\emph{(b) RSLE Absolute Errors with $\mathbf{N(0,0.01^{2})}$}}},grid=both, every major grid/.style={gray, opacity=0.5}]
\addplot [only marks,mark=*,red,mark options={scale=.65}]table[x index=0,y index=3,col sep=comma, green, only marks] {data.csv};\label{plots:plot3}
\addplot [only marks,mark=*,blue,mark options={scale=.65}]table[x index=0,y index=4,col sep=comma, green, only marks] {data.csv};
\coordinate (bot) at (rel axis cs:1,0);
\end{groupplot}

\path (top-|current bounding box.west)--
  node[anchor=south,rotate=90] {\large{\bf{Absolute Parameter Error ($\mid$Estimated - Actual$\mid$})}}
  (bot-|current bounding box.west);
% legend
\path (top|-current bounding box.north)--
  coordinate(legendpos)
  (bot|-current bounding box.north);
\matrix[
matrix of nodes,
anchor=south,
draw,
inner sep=0.2em,
draw
  ]at([yshift=1ex]legendpos)
  {
\ref{plots:plot1}& $\delta r_{2}$ &[5pt]
\ref{plots:plot2}& $\delta r_{3}$ &[5pt]\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption[Plot showing Absolute Errors with noise with parameters for RLSE.]{Plot showing RLSE Absolute Errors with noise with parameters (a) $N(0,0.001^{2})$ and (b) $N(0,0.001^{2})$.}\label{abserror}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `ymin=0, ymax=0.005`?

Comment: my plots for some reason are not showing up correctly, i.e. they do not seem to be using the points from the .csv file contents.  Were you able to plot from the filecontents input?

Comment: I can plot the data given in the `filecontents` environment. Initially I had a problem because I already had a different `data.csv` file in the same directory. What is the specific problem you are seeing?

Comment: @LucaD, you solved my problem.  I also had a file with the same name that was messing me up.  Thanks.

Comment: Hello,  how to show the numbers on the y-axis as floating, i.e. like 0.005, instead of 1.10^-3?

Comment: I realized it because I saw a warning "LaTeX Warning: File `data.csv' already exists on the system.    Not generating it from this source."

Comment: Casually I had a `data.csv` in my system too. :D

Comment: Adding `yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/precision=4}` and `scaled y ticks = false` to groupplot options should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not really clear from the question, but the problem turned out to be another file named `data.csv` in the same directory. In this case a warning is emitted and the old file is used:

```
LaTeX Warning: File `data.csv' already exists on the system.
Not generating it from this source.
```

To format the number as you want you can write `\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=3}` and, to avoid scaling all the ticks, the pgfplots option `scaling ticks=false`.

```
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable, booktabs}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots, matrix}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10, title/.append style={align =center}}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=3}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
  Iter  abs11  abs21  abs12  abs22
     1, 0.0016930, 0.0007109, 0.0169301, 0.0071087
     2, 0.0004656, 0.0006430, 0.0046563, 0.0064301
     3, 0.0001496, 0.0010624, 0.0014964, 0.0106239
     4, 0.0000946, 0.0006596, 0.0009458, 0.0065962
     5, 0.0000274, 0.0002370, 0.0002737, 0.0023697
     6, 0.0000388, 0.0001168, 0.0003882, 0.0011681
     7, 0.0000232, 0.0001592, 0.0002324, 0.0015921
     8, 0.0000073, 0.0001997, 0.0000728, 0.0019965
     9, 0.0001358, 0.0002963, 0.0013578, 0.0029635
    10, 0.0000410, 0.0002793, 0.0004099, 0.0027925
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotsset{minor grid style={dashed,red}}
\pgfplotsset{major grid style={dotted,green!50!black}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={
  group size= 1  by 2,
  vertical sep=2cm,
  horizontal sep = 2cm,
  ylabels at=edge left,group name=ape},
  width=15cm,
  height=8cm,
  try min ticks=5,
  scaled ticks=false,
  ]
\nextgroupplot[align =center, 
title={\textbf{\emph{(a) RSLE Absolute Errors with $\mathbf{N(0,0.001^{2})}$}}}, 
grid=both, every major grid/.style={gray, opacity=0.5}
]

\addplot [only marks,mark=*,red,mark options={scale=.65}]table[x    index=0,y index=1,col sep=comma, green, only marks]    {data.csv};\label{plots:plot1}
\addplot [only marks,mark=*,blue,mark options={scale=.65}]table[x index=0,y index=2,col sep=comma, green, only marks] {data.csv};\label{plots:plot2}
\coordinate (top) at (rel axis cs:0,1);

\nextgroupplot[title = {\textbf{\emph{(b) RSLE Absolute Errors with $\mathbf{N(0,0.01^{2})}$}}},grid=both, every major grid/.style={gray, opacity=0.5}]
\addplot [only marks,mark=*,red,mark options={scale=.65}]table[x index=0,y index=3,col sep=comma, green, only marks] {data.csv};\label{plots:plot3}
\addplot [only marks,mark=*,blue,mark options={scale=.65}]table[x index=0,y index=4,col sep=comma, green, only marks] {data.csv};
\coordinate (bot) at (rel axis cs:1,0);
\end{groupplot}

\path (top-|current bounding box.west)--
  node[anchor=south,rotate=90] {\large{\bf{Absolute Parameter Error ($\mid$Estimated - Actual$\mid$})}}
  (bot-|current bounding box.west);
% legend
\path (top|-current bounding box.north)--
  coordinate(legendpos)
  (bot|-current bounding box.north);
\matrix[
matrix of nodes,
anchor=south,
draw,
inner sep=0.2em,
draw
  ]at([yshift=1ex]legendpos)
  {
\ref{plots:plot1}& $\delta r_{2}$ &[5pt]
\ref{plots:plot2}& $\delta r_{3}$ &[5pt]\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption[Plot showing Absolute Errors with noise with parameters for RLSE.]{Plot showing RLSE Absolute Errors with noise with parameters (a) $N(0,0.001^{2})$ and (b) $N(0,0.001^{2})$.}\label{abserror}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```